# Is there a way to add newlines to a table to create sub-groups?

Tags: text-processing

I'm having a lot of difficulty figuring out how to phrase this so Google-fu is failing.

I have a text file with a table of data.  I'd like to insert newlines to visually separate subgroups.

For example, if I start with:

```
jan   ford
jan   trillian
mar   trillian
sep   marvin
```

And the first field is my subgroup field then the output should be:

```
jan   ford
jan   trillian

mar   trillian

sep   marvin
```

I can do something like `^(a-z){3}\t(.*)\n\1\t(.*)$` to identify two lines where the month is the same but I don't know how to match when they're different.

Ideally I'd love this to be a regex I can throw into BBedit but I'm open to other solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `bbedit` is some kind of paid OSX editor. I'm afraid I;ve never used it and can't install it so I can't help you there. Based on the regex you show, it has its own regular expression syntax so it's unlikely you'll find a solution on a general *nix site using it. However, here are a couple of other options. In both, the idea is to save the first field and print a blank line if it is different than the one seen on the previous line:

```
$ awk '{if($1!=last && NR>1){print ""}last=$1;}1;' file
jan ford
jan trillian

mar trillian

sep marvin
```

`awk` is a scripting language that is designed to deal with field-based data. It will automatically split each line into fields which can then be referred to as `$1`,`$2` ... `$N`. So, the script above will save the first field in the variable `last`, and for each line but the first (that's what the `NR>1` means), it will print an empty line if `last` is not the same as the currently saved value. The `1;` is awk shorthand for "print every line".

Alternatively, you could also do this in `perl`:

```
$ perl -lape '$F[0] ne $last && $.>1 && print ""; $last=$F[0]' file
jan ford
jan trillian

mar trillian

sep marvin
```

Here, we're using `perl` command line switches to do most of the work. The `-a` makes `perl` act like `awk` and split each input line into the array `@F`. Therefore, `$F[0]` is the first field. The `-l` makes `perl` add a newline to each `print` call, so `print ""` just prints an empty line. The `-p` makes it print each input line after applying the script given by `-e`. The script itself is exactly the same as the `awk` one above.

Comment: BBEdit has a free cousin called TextWrangler if you want to look at it.

Comment: I asked here largely because Google brought me here and I was okay with *nix style solutions.  The regex should be standard but I think it wasn't displaying properly.  Looks okay now.  Awk, which I don't use often so didn't think about, works nicely,  Thanks, and I very much appreciate the explanation with the answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk 'NR > 1 && $1 != last {print ""}; {print; last = $1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you can match the dups, then you'll want to negate your action. You could do like:

```sh
sed -e'/^\n/!{$n;G;N;s/^\(\(...\).*\)\n\2/\1\2/;}' -eP\;D <in >out
```

In other words start with a double spaced file, and prune out the second space between your groups.

Running that against your example input prints:

```
jan   ford
jan   trillian

mar   trillian

sep   marvin
```

Which actually leads me to a question for you: I think I get how Trillian might have two birthdays with the parallel universes and all, but could you explain why you think Marvin might have one at all? I guess September would fit, though - it's always gloomy.

---

Here's another one, courtesy @don_crissti *(if slightly modified)*:

```sh
sed -etD -e'$q;N;/^\(...\).*\n\1/!s/\n/&&/;:D' -eP\;D
```

I like his a lot better. He initially asked me: *why edit out the newlines and not just edit them in?* I didn't have any answer, really, and was mostly ambivalent because I didn't consider it to make much of a difference.

The thing is, though, the lookahead technique used here requires a knife-edge buffer - it could report false positives if the buffer grows any larger than the most current two input lines at a time. Balancing a single line of lookahead gets to be more difficult when you're also actually inserting newlines into the very same stream you're matching and requires that you can easily distinguish between a line of input you've inserted or a line you need to read. That balance requires *at least* one extra test per cycle - and I get by with the `/^\n/!` test above.

But a very basic part of the `sed` machinery is the `s///`ubstitution statement's `t`ested return, which does conditional branching in the event of success. Because his substitutions always generate an extra line the `sed` line cycle - which is what clears a `t`est's return - does not roll over when pattern space is `D`eleted and `t`est still works at the top of the script. In this way don can very simply `t`est over every insertion and reliably evaluate the result of the previous iteration at the top of the next.

So go upvote one of his answers, cause I guess he isn't going to put it here.

---

The `G`et command appends `sed`'s hold space to pattern space following an inserted `\n`ewline delimiter. The hold space is never used here, though, and so all that is `G`ot is the `\n`ewline.

The `N`ext command appends the `N`ext input line to pattern space following an inserted `\n`ewline delimiter. Doing `G`et then `N`ext for each input line gets two `\n`ewlines per input line.