# Insert newline before each line matching a pattern unless the previous line is already empty

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to add a new line before any line containing a pattern where we can assume that the pattern is always the first string of the current line. For example

```
This is a
pattern
This is a
pattern
```

I can add a new line with the `sed` command

```
sed -i 's/pattern\+/\n&/g' file
```

to get the output

```
This is a

pattern
This is a

pattern
```

To prevent multiple new lines being added (in case of multiple execution) I want to check whether the line before the pattern is empty. I know I can do that with

```
if [ "$line" == "" ]; then
```

**But how do I determine the previous line, of a matching pattern, in the first place?**

EDIT: Pattern can occur multiple times.

Comment: That's right. And yes it is possible that the pattern can occur multiple times in a file. After looking into the answer from @maulinglawns it's probably better to use another language because `grep` is only applied to the first found line

Comment: Note, if you want to limit blank lines in your file you can alway run a substitution after-the-fact. In the Raku programming language (fomerly Perl_6), running the one-liner `raku -e 'put S/\n**3..*/\n\n/ given slurp();'` converts any two-or-more consecutive blank lines to a single blank line. https://raku.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could store the previous line in the hold space:

```
sed '
 /^pattern/{
   x
   /./ {
     x
     s/^/\
/
     x
   }
   x
 }
 h'
```

It would be more legible with `awk` though:

```
awk '!previous_empty && /pattern/ {print ""}
     {previous_empty = $0 == ""; print}'
```

Like the GNU implementations of `sed` has a `-i` option for in-place editing, the GNU implementation of `awk` has `-i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk`¹ for that.

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>

Answer (score 4):

I know your question was initially about sed, but there is a beautifully simple answer in vim:

```
:g/.\npattern/norm o
```

Or, if you would rather run this entirely from the command line:

```
vim file -c "g/.\npattern/norm o" -c "wq"
```

The way it works, is that it looks for any line that matches the following regex:

```
.\npattern
```

which is any non-empty line followed by your pattern. Then, for each match, it applies the following command `norm o`, which opens up a newline below the current cursor location.

Comment: I can't find any mention in [POSIX `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) or [POSIX `vi`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) of multi-line regexes; pretty sure this is Vim-specific.  It may be worth noting that in Vim, `.` matches any *non-newline* character, whereas `\_.` matches any character including a newline.  (See `:help /\_.` from within Vim.)

Answer (score 3):

> But how do I determine the previous line, of a matching pattern, in
>   the first place?

Umm... perhaps this will work.

Using `grep` and the `-B` switch:

```
 -B num, --before-context=num
         Print num lines of leading context before each match.  See
         also the -A and -C options.
```

Consider this infile:

```
cat infile 
foo

bar
baz
```

Now, if I `grep` for `bar`, the previous line should be empty:

```
if [[ $(grep -B 1 'bar' infile | head -1) == "" ]]; then echo "line is empty"; fi
line is empty
```

As opposed to using `grep` on `baz`, where the previous line is **not** empty:

```
if [[ $(grep -B 1 'baz' infile | head -1) == "" ]]; then echo "line is empty"; fi
<no output>
```

Comment: What if you have multiple lines that match the pattern ?

Comment: Then I would use Python!

Answer (score 3):

Another way with `sed`:

```
sed -e 'tD' -e '$!N;/.\npattern/s/\n/&&/;:D' -e 'P;D' infile
```

This was [explained in detail here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239482): it's basically an `N;P;D` cycle where we account for the newlines we edit in, so each time the script inserts a `\n`ewline it executes only `P` and `D` without `N` so as to always have only two lines in the pattern space.

Comment: Though this solution will not insert a newline before the first line of input if it matches... which may or may not be what you want. To always insert add `-e '1{/pattern/{x;p;x;};}'` before `-e 'tD'`

Answer (score 2):

If we have gnused (the default in Linux and many others, and available for all)

```
sed -zri  's/([^\n]\n)(pattern)/\1\n\2/g' file
```

where

- `([^\n]\n)(pattern)` the pattern after a non-empty line
- `-z` separate "lines" by the null char (slurp the file)
- `-r` to have extended regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

### Using [`ex`, POSIX specified features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) only

```
printf '%s\n' 0a '' . 1d 'g/pattern/-put | -,.!uniq' x | ex file
```

---

Quick summary of the commands passed to `ex` by `printf`:

```
0a - append after line 0
   - an empty line
.  - stop appending
1d - delete line 1 (the new empty line) into the unnamed register (a.k.a. buffer)

g/pattern/-put | -,.!uniq

g/pattern/ - for every line in the file matching "pattern"
- - on the *previous* line,
put - "put" (linewise append) the contents of the unnamed register
| - and also do the following (still part of the g// command)
-,. - take the previous and current lines
!uniq - and run them through the external command "uniq"
        (replacing the lines with the output)

x - save changes and exit
```

`ex` is worth learning.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we reframe the requirements like this:

- We have a file of paragraphs, which are regions of consecutive non-empty lines, separated by one or more empty lines.
- Whenever "pattern" occurs inside a paragraph, we would like that line to start a new paragraph, except when "pattern" occurs in the first line of a paragraph.
- Furthermore, we do not mind normalizing the file so that there is **exactly** one empty line between the paragraphs, and no stray empty lines at the beginning or end.*

If these requirements are acceptable, we can take advantage of Awk paragraph mode (enabled an empty value in `RS`):

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n" }
           { print sep $1;
             for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
             { if ($i ~ /pat/) print ""; print $i }
             sep=FS }'
```

In paragraph mode, the records are paragraphs. Because we are using `\n` as `FS`, the fields `$1, $2, ... $NF` correspond to lines of paragraphs. For instance, if `NF` is 5, then we are dealing with a five line paragraph. The paragraph-separating newlines are removed and each record `$0` contains only the interior newlines between the lines, and the field splitting is done on these.

A paragraph has at least one line, because paragraphs cannot be empty: an empty paragraph looks like two consecutive newlines which are part of the same paragraph separating sequence.

So, without checking that `NF` is at least 1, we just print the first paragraph line with `print sep $1`. The first time around, `sep` is empty so is of no consequence; but after the first paragraph, we set `sep` to a newline, so that the next `print sep $1` will generate the paragraph separation.

After printing the first line, we iterate over the remaining lines, if any, and print them. Here, we check whether each line matches the pattern. If so, we issue an extra blank line before printing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 'BEGIN my @a = 0; @a.push(.chars); my $a = @a.shift;   \
             $a == 0 ?? s:g/ ^pattern /replacement/ !! s:g/ ^pattern /\nreplacement/; '  file
```

Sample Input:

```
First line

This is a
pattern X
This is a

pattern Y
This is a
pattern Z

Last line
```

Sample Output:

```
First line

This is a

replacement X
This is a

replacement Y
This is a

replacement Z

Last line
```

Briefly, in the first line (3 statements) the `@a` array is set-up as a 2-element `push`/`shift` mini stack, so that the `$a` variable gets the `.chars` of the previous line (obviously, the `.chars` before starting to read the file is zero--hence pre-populating the array with `0` in the first position).

In the second line Raku's ternary operator  **Test** `??` **True** `!!` **False**  is used to determine which `replacement` is used, with or without `\n` prepended.

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_??_!!
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#s///_in-place_substitution
https://raku.org