# Remove all lines between two similar patterns if a specific pattern in between is not matched

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, terminal

The title should be: `Remove all lines between two similar patterns, including the line of the starting pattern. if another specific pattern in between is not matched`. I made it shorter because its more readable for others searching for answers on Google.

About the questions: I have a list of listable shares and unreable shares for a specific computer. I want to create a list of all computers that have listable shares and delete their unreadable shares. But I stumble two problems. Firstly, with correctly deleting all lines between two simular patterns. Secondly, how not to delete the lines between two simular words if a specific pattern is found.

My input is

```
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-5:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        E$
        H$
        IPC$

Shares for DED-SHD-ED-6:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        print$
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-7:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-8:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$

Shares for DED-SHD-ED-9:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
        VBRCatalog
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
```

I managed to strip all unreadable shares with the following command `awk '/Listable Shares/,/Shares for/' input.txt`, the problem with this command is that `DED-SHD-ED-8` have no `Listable Shares`. It strips the computer `DED-SHD-ED-9` below and I will see the Listable shares of `DED-SHD-ED-9` at `DED-SHD-ED-8`

See the output below (I know the name of the first computer in the list is missing but this is not an issue for me)

```
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        print$
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-7:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-8:
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
```

To solve this issue I had the idea the strip all computers WITHOUT Listable shares before I run `awk '/Listable Shares/,/Shares for/' input.txt`. At first I tried to delete all lines between "Shares for" and "Shares for". I looked around on the forum and tried to make the more simple answers to work and avoided the complicated ones because they go out of my understanding at the moment. For example I used this command `sed '/^Shares for/,/^Shares for/{//!d;};' input.txt` and `sed '/Shares for/,/:/{//!d;};' input2.txt` In here it strips half of the lines between the computers.

Output

```
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-5:
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-6:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        print$
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-7:
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-8:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
```

Why it strips the data of only half of the computers? I don't see why

My next idea was to add an excluding to the command to not delete the lines between "Shares for" and "Shares for" if the pattern `Listable` is matched in these lines. And then delete the computers with no data left like `DED-SHD-ED-5` and `DED-SHD-ED-7`. But maybe this is not the best approach. Maybe its better to delete the line of the first pattern is the pattern "Listable" is not seen.

I would love some help and insights how to propely process this all.

Expected output:

```
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-6:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        print$
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-7:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-9:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
        VBRCatalog
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
```

Comment: Is the presence of empty lines between the records arbitrary?

Comment: @tink No its not random. The presence of the empty line is actually only there when `Listable Shares` is missing

Comment: How does this file get generated? Can you add extra new lines easily?

Comment: An application. No I can't add new extra lines easily

Comment: OK - I'll have a go at it as it stands.

Comment: Do `Unreadable` shares always come before `Listable` shares, unless one or the other is absent? And...why does your last "Expected Output" example still show `Unreadable` shares? (Seems like that's the one you're trying to eliminate... ).

Comment: @EdMorton Updated answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?  `shares` being the file-name I picked for your sample input.

```
sed -e 'tD' -e '$!N;/.\nShares/s/\n/&&/;:D' -e 'P;D' shares | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n";FS="\n"}/Listable/'
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-6:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        print$
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-7:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-9:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
        VBRCatalog
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
```

The `sed` basically inserts a newline before `Shares` if there isn't one already - that's so we can use newlines as the record separator (`RS="\n\n"`) in `awk`. Then it is simply a question of only printing records that have the word `Listable` in them.

Comment: It works! But could you add a bit of explanation? I want to learn from it

Comment: @pwrsheller - I had started adding some commentary before you requested it ;) My edit was finished a second after your comment ;D  The `sed` part shamelessly snaffled from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239478/is-there-a-way-to-add-newlines-to-a-table-to-create-sub-groups/239482#239482) ...

Answer (score 2):

Understanding:

- print a `Shares` block if said block contains the string `Listable Shares`

Once you bring `awk` into the mix you can usually eliminate the need for `sed`.

One (verbose) `awk` idea:

```
$ cat shares.awk

NF == 0           { next }                        # skip blank lines
$1 == "Shares"    { if (print_block)              # if 1st field is "Shares"; if flag is set (==1) then ...
                       print block                # print the previous block
                    print_block = 0               # clear the flag
                    block = $0                    # initialize a new block
                    next                          # skip to next input line
                  }
/Listable Shares/ { print_block = 1 }             # if line contains "Listable Shares" then set flag
                  { block = block ORS $0 }        # append current line to end of block
END               { if (print_block)              # flush last block to stdout?
                       print block
                  }
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ awk -f shares.awk input.txt
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-6:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        print$
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-7:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-9:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
        VBRCatalog
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e '.put for slurp.comb(/^^Shares .*? <?before ^^Shares | $ >/).grep(/Listable/);'   file 

#OR:

~$ raku -e '.put for lines.join("\n").comb(/^^Shares .*? <?before ^^Shares | $ >/).grep(/Listable/);'   file
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. In an operation which might be considered the converse of destructive `split`ting on a regex pattern, Raku provides the `comb` routine which allows you to select out elements of your choosing. Above, The input file is broken into records by `.comb(/^^Shares .*? <?before ^^Shares | $ >/)` selecting for records that have:

- `^^Shares` start-of-line text "Shares",
- `.*?` non-greedy any number of characters,
- `<?before ^^Shares | $ >` a positive lookahead which says to stop the pattern `?before` the next `^^Shares` record pattern is seen, or `$` before/at the end of the file itself.

In the second operation in the chain `grep` is used to return only those records that contain a `Listable` block.

Sample Input:

```
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-5:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        E$
        H$
        IPC$

Shares for DED-SHD-ED-6:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        print$
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-7:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-8:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$

Shares for DED-SHD-ED-9:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
        VBRCatalog
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
```

Sample Output:

```
Shares for DED-SHD-ED-6:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        print$

Shares for DED-SHD-ED-7:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2

Shares for DED-SHD-ED-9:
    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]
        ADMIN$
        C$
        IPC$
        VBRCatalog
    [--- Listable Shares ---]
        backup      backup2
```

Note: It is often instructive to look at how a language internally represents data, so here is the output *after* `comb`ing into separate records but *before* `grep`ping for the desired block:

```
~$ raku -e '.raku.put for slurp.comb(/^^Shares .*? <?before ^^Shares | $ >/);'   file
"Shares for DED-SHD-ED-5:\n    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]\n        ADMIN\$\n        C\$\n        E\$\n        H\$\n        IPC\$\n\n"
"Shares for DED-SHD-ED-6:\n    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]\n        ADMIN\$\n        C\$\n        IPC\$\n    [--- Listable Shares ---]\n        print\$\n"
"Shares for DED-SHD-ED-7:\n    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]\n        ADMIN\$\n        C\$\n        IPC\$\n    [--- Listable Shares ---]\n        backup      backup2\n"
"Shares for DED-SHD-ED-8:\n    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]\n        ADMIN\$\n        C\$\n        IPC\$\n\n"
"Shares for DED-SHD-ED-9:\n    [--- Unreadable Shares ---]\n        ADMIN\$\n        C\$\n        IPC\$\n        VBRCatalog\n    [--- Listable Shares ---]\n        backup      backup2\n\n"
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Operators
https://docs.raku.org/routine/comb
https://docs.raku.org/routine/grep
https://raku.org